# Strange alignment when using tilde as the not operator in logic

Tags: spacing, symbols, logic

I wish to use ~ which has latex symbol: `\sim`  for the negation sign in logic. `\sim` and `\neg` are the two most frequent symbols for negation in logic.

However, I get a strange looking result if I use `\sim`. The spacing with the variables is odd as the `\sim` is further from the variable. Compare the alternative using `\neg` and you will see what I mean.

1. How can I fix the spacing/alignment?
2. How can I show the results of my LateX code on SE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For showing a typeset result, make a PNG image of it (I use the screen snapshot feature of my OS) and upload it by clicking on the small window icon on top of the editing window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\sim` is a relational symbol (like `=`), the spacing around is quite large (`\thickmuskip`). In LaTeX it is defined as:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sim}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"18}
```

`\neg` is a `\mathord` and is defined as:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\neg}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3A}
```

Thus you can define a `\lsim` as `\mathord`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lsim}{\mathord}{symbols}{"18}
```

Or `\lsim` can be defined using `\sim`:

```
\newcommand*{\lsim}{\mathord{\sim}}
```

Comment: How would I learn about something like this on my own? Note that I use emacs and there could possibly be documentation or autocompletion available?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: "The TeXbook" by Donald E. Knuth, "Chapter 18: Fine Points of Mathematics Typing". Or "[TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)" by Victor Eijkhout, "Chapter 23: Mathematics Typesetting".